# show specific image for field content

Tags: html, css, image, cakephp

I am creating the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `videothek9`.`movies` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `release_year` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `available` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

and baking it with the cakephp bake console.

Here is an example for the standard movies/index page:

[image]

The "available" field can be 0 or 1. Now i want to show specific images instead of 0 or 1, like a checkmark tick or a red x-mark. The cakephp cookbook (html helper section) didnt help me much...

And here a piece of the view code

```
<?php foreach ($movies as $movie): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo h($movie['Movie']['id']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($movie['Movie']['title']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($movie['Movie']['release_year']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($movie['Movie']['available']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="actions">
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $movie['Movie']['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('action' => 'edit', $movie['Movie']['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $movie['Movie']['id']), array(), __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $movie['Movie']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Can I just place a normal php if/else statement in the Movies Controller ?

Comment: What do you mean with "Now i want to show specific images instead of 0 or 1"? By default a TINYINT(1) field is baked as a checkbox in your view, not as a 0/1 select.

Comment: I mean the Movies/index Page. Here are all Movies listed (Id, Title, Year and available status) In the available field is either printed a 1 or 0. The Tinyint/Checkbox is only printed in the Movies/add Page.

Comment: That's the kind of information that you should add to your question. Including a code snippet of the baked view code wouldn't hurt either, as the problem might not be obvious to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super simple.. just do it with the `if else` statement.and display image or anything you want

```
If (0)
  echo $this->Html->image('tick.png');
Else
  echo $this->Html->image('cross.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. Instead of echoing the value of "available" field use [HtmlHelper::image()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3aimage) to echo img tag with image of your choice.